# Next 13 api throwing res.status is not a function

Tags: rest, next.js, runtime-error

I'm making my first next js application and im facing problems with the rest api, in this moment i have **/app/api/isWorking/route.ts**, this route countain this simple test api:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "working" });
}
```

and i call this api in **app/account/page.tsx**

```
"use client";

export default function Account() {
  const testApi = () => {
    fetch("/api/isWorking")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.message);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data: " + error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={testApi} className="">
        test api
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and it's giving me this error:

```
- error TypeError: res.status is not a function
    at GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/isWorking/route.ts:6:9)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:254:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:111:36)
    at NoopContextManager.with (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:360:30)
    at ContextAPI.with (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:30:58)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:953:34)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:993:36)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:100:107)
    at NoopContextManager.with (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:360:30)
    at ContextAPI.with (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:30:58)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:100:32)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:242:53)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at Object.wrap (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/async-storage/static-generation-async-storage-wrapper.js:42:24)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:196:97)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at Object.wrap (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/async-storage/request-async-storage-wrapper.js:82:24)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:195:75)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at AppRouteRouteModule.execute (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:192:56)
    at AppRouteRouteModule.handle (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:315:41)
```

I'm using node 20.6.1

I've tried to search this error but it doesn't seem like anyone is having this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sir, here you go!
Please update your **/app/api/isWorking/route.ts**

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
 
  const result = {
    message: "working",
  };
  return NextResponse.json(result, {
    status: 200,
  });
}
```